# If $A$ is $\kappa\text{-Suslin}$ then so is $pA$.

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

So there is this proposition in "The Higher Infinite", that I have a problem with, and I need some help.

---

The prop.

> Proposition. Suppose that $A \subseteq {^k(^\omega\omega)}$ and that $\kappa \gt 1$. If $A$ is $\kappa\text{-Suslin}$, then so is $pA$.
>   Proof. If a tree $T$ on ${^k\omega} \times \kappa$ is such that $A = p[T]$, then that tree recast as $T'$ on ${^{k-1}\omega} \times (\omega \times \kappa)$ is such that $pA = p[T']$. The result follows by applying a bijection:$\omega \times \kappa \rightarrow \kappa$.

---

So I am totally fine with the proof except for one small detail: what happens when $\kappa$ is finite? We can't have the bijection in the proof. So I naturally tried using a surjection but that has counter-examples to it. So my question is, is this true for finite $\kappa$? If so, can you give me a hint towards the solution please?

Comment: Can't you just take a bijection of $\omega\times\kappa$ with $\omega$ instead?

Comment: But I want to show that it is $\kappa\text{-Suslin}$.

Comment: Is there even a meaning to $n$-Suslin, though?

Comment: Actually since this is my first time encoutering this property, I don't have much of an idea(intuition) what these mean except for the formal definition. So having this in mind, does what you're saying mean that $n\text{-Suslin}$ collapses to just having a tree on ${^k\omega}$ s.t. $A = [T]$? And so that $A$ is closed?

Comment: I mean, it sure sounds like it. I'll take a look at some notes later to see if my intuition is close to reality. Hopefully by then someone who knows more about this topic will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall any uses of $\kappa$-Suslin for *finite* $\kappa$. But Asaf's intuition is correct: $A\subseteq {^k(^\omega\omega)}$ is $n$-Suslin if and only if $A$ is closed.

The direct implication holds because if $A$ is $Y$-Suslin for $Y$, then $A$ is the projection of a closed subset of $^k(^\omega\omega)\times {}^\omega Y$, and if $Y$ is finite then $^\omega Y$ is compact. It is generally true that that the projection of a closed subset of $B\times C$ onto $B$ (where both $B,C$ are separable metrizable and $C$ is compact) must be closed. The reverse implication is trivial.

In any case, the correct statement of the quoted proposition is

> Suppose that $A \subseteq {^k(^\omega\omega)}$ and that $\mathbf{k}>1$. If $A$ is $\boldsymbol\kappa$-Suslin, …

So it is just a typographical confusion.